# when to use dev vs distribution push notification p12 certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app is not released yet, so you couldn't find it in the App Store. But it is being used by a group of private beta users (through the iOS TestFlight service). And it is hitting my production server, which is the reason for the question.

In the situation described above, what `.p12` do I use? the Dev certificate or the Distribution certificate? I am asking because I am not clear on whom the distinction is for. As far as my server is concerned I don't care which one is used. I just need to send push notifications, and as long as the users get them, I am happy. And since I am using my production server, I figure I should use the production/distribution certificate. But I have a suspicion that my server -- dev or production -- has nothing to do with it. And which certificate I use may entirely have to do with the App Store. So will someone please clarify for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

**Development** If your app is running in Debug mode and is signed with the Development provisioning profile (Code Signing Identity is “iPhone Developer”), then your server must be using the Development certificate.

**Production** Apps that are distributed as Ad Hoc or on the App Store (when Code Signing Identify is “iPhone Distribution”) must talk to a server that uses the Production certificate. If there is a mismatch between these, push notifications cannot be delivered to your app.